# Error in salesOrderRepositoryV1;content type application/soap+xml;

Tags: magento2, soap, web-services, magento-2.1.1, vb.net

I am using Magento EE 2.1.1 version.

While using web service `salesOrderRepositoryV1` to get the order details. I'm getting error as below:

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=The content type application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:m="https%3A%2F%2Fint-en.ctv-it.net%2Fsoap%2Fen%3Fservices%3DsalesOrderRepositoryV1%26wsdl%3D1">
   <env:Body>
      <env:Fault>
         <env:Code>
            <env:Value>env:Receiver</env:Value>
         </env:Code>
         <env:Reason>
            <env:Text xml:lang="en">Invalid XML</env:Text>
         </env:Reason>
         <env:Detail><m:GenericFault><m:Trace>&lt;![CDATA[#0 /var/www/magento2-fastest/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/Soap/Server.php(121): Magento\Webapi\Model\Soap\Server-&gt;_checkRequest('')
#1 /var/www/magento2-fastest/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Model/Soap/Server/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Webapi\Model\Soap\Server-&gt;handle()
#2 /var/www/magento2-fastest/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Soap.php(145): Magento\Webapi\Model\Soap\Server\Proxy-&gt;handle()
#3 /var/www/magento2-fastest/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Soap'.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
```

Below is the C# code:

```
private void GetSalesorderId()
        {
            var salesOrderRepositoryV1GetRequest = new SalesOrderRepositoryV1GetRequest()
            {
                id = "5066613153"
            };
            var client = new salesOrderRepositoryV1PortTypeClient();
            var response = client.salesOrderRepositoryV1Get(salesOrderRepositoryV1GetRequest);

        }
```

Code in `Web.Config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="salesOrderRepositoryV1Binding">
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                    <httpTransport />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://baseurl/soap/ar?services=salesOrderRepositoryV1"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="salesOrderRepositoryV1Binding"
                contract="ServiceReference1.salesOrderRepositoryV1PortType"
                name="salesOrderRepositoryV1Port" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Please someone help in resolving this. I have tried multiple solutions from forums, but nothing is working for me.

Any help is appreciated?